# How to intercept fastcgi errors conditionally in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to set directive fastcgi_intercept_errors on only when my $request_uri is in some particular format.

Here is what I did,

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/b/c){
  error_page 502 @static;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

But it gives me error that fastcgi_intercept_errors directive is not allowed here.

Any way out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you try to test `$uri` and/or `$request_uri` with an `if`, you should consider using `location` instead. That is, try something like this instead:

```
location ~* /a/b/c {
    fastcgi_pass ...
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    ...
}
```

Some additional details about `if` in nginx can be found at http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil.